# How to plot (isosurface!) a datafile with four columns (x,y,z,f(x,y,z))? Is is possible using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

What are the possible ways to plot (isosurface!) a datafile with four columns (x,y,z,f(x,y,z))? Is it possible using gnuplot?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with `gnuplot`, but you might want to use `octave`, which uses `gnuplot` as backend (still). There, see the [isosurface](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/isosurface.html) function.